# Lenguaje C en Linux: chdir devuelve valor -1 siempre

Tags: c, linux

La siguiente función recibe un array de strings (`**args`) y, en concreto, `args[1]` contendría el path al ejecutar la línea.

Esta función forma parte de un programa que tiene un método para leer una linea desde el terminal y otro método para dividir la línea en tokens, el resultado se almacena en la variable `args`.

Sea cual sea el path, mediante la ejecución de: cd /home, por ejemplo, el `int i` resultante siempre obtiene el valor de "-1" y no realiza la función de `chdir` que quería.

```
int internal_cd(char **args){

    char *directorio=args[1];
    printf("%s",directorio);
    int i=chdir(directorio);
    chdir(directorio);
    printf("%d",i);

    if(chdir(args[1])==-1) printf("Error en la ruta especificada\n");


    char cwd[1024];

    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL){
        fprintf(stdout, "Directorio actual: %s\n", cwd);
    }
    else{
        perror("getcwd() error");
    }
}
```

@eferion
Mediante el siguiente método recibo una linea desde teclado con la función fgets y tras analizarla descubro que junto los carácteres que la componen, el último resulta ser algún tipo de carácter especial que es el que me impedía realizar el chdir.
Con el bucle de más adelante retiro ese carácter pero realmente me gustaría saber por qué tras el fgets me incluye ese carácter para saber si me podría ahorrar el bucle("parche") que he incluido más adelante.

```
/* read_line imprime el PROMPT y devuelve la linea introducida por      teclado*/
char *read_line(char *line){
    printf("%s",PROMPT);
//El último carácter de lineAux tras fgets me devuelve un valor especial al final de la linea, en el bucle lo
            //eliminaremos.
    char *lineAux =(char *)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    fgets(lineAux,1000,stdin);

    int i=strlen(lineAux);
    int z=0;

while(z<i-1){
            line[z]=lineAux[z];
    z++;
}
    fflush(stdout);
return line;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi prueba y no he tenido problemas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int internal_cd(char **args){

    char *directorio=args[1];
    printf("%s",directorio);
    int i=chdir(directorio);

    chdir(directorio);
    printf("%d",i);

    if(chdir(args[1])==-1) printf("Error en la ruta especificada\n");


    char cwd[1024];

    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL){
        fprintf(stdout, "Directorio actual: %s\n", cwd);
    }
    else{
        perror("getcwd() error");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    internal_cd(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Entrada:

```
./a.out /home
```

Salida:

```
/home0
Directorio actual: /home
```

Answer (score 0):

`chdir` no necesita la instrucción de `cd`. Si lo que llega a `args[1]` es algo tal que `cd /home` lo que tienes que hacer es, en primer lugar, eliminar los tres primeros caracteres.

Una forma de simular dicha eliminación sería la siguiente:

```
chdir(args[1]+3));
```

Si aún así sigue sin funcionarte, verifica que la cadena no tiene caracteres extraños al final de la cadena (como saltos de línea).